# Batch script to find, replace and output new file and sum one each time

Tags: batch-file, mkv

I`m editing a bunch of files with mkvmerge and I'm doing this:

Video from `original-001.mkv` mux with audio from `audio-001.mkv` and add subtitle from `sub-001.mkv`.

I'm creating a bunch of .bat scripts and using notapad++ find and replace function to do this:

find 001 and replace for 002, save as 002.bat and move on.

Basically, there will always be a base file named 001.bat

What would be really great is this Notepad++ portion could be automated. 
Find all strings "001", replace with "002", save as 002.bat
Find "002", replace with "003", save as 003.bat.

Up to 300.

And finally what I do is another script:
Call 001.bat
Call 002.bat and so on. 
If I file doesn't exist there's no problem.

Is this possible using batch script on windows?

EDIT to add code as the way I'm going now:
Example of 001.bat

```
"C:/Program Files/MKVToolNix\mkvmerge.exe" --ui-language en --output ^"F:\original\original-001 ^(1^).mkv^" --language 0:eng --default-track 0:yes --language 1:eng --default-track 1:yes ^"^(^" ^"F:\original\original-001.mkv^" ^"^)^" --no-video --language 1:por ^"^(^" ^"F:\BR001.mp4^" ^"^)^" --track-order 0:0,0:1,1:1
```

And I have this (but it's powershell)

```
powershell -Command "(gc 001.bat) -replace '001', '002' | Out-File 002.bat"
powershell -Command "(gc 002.bat) -replace '002', '003' | Out-File 003.bat"
powershell -Command "(gc 003.bat) -replace '003', '004' | Out-File 004.bat"
powershell -Command "(gc 004.bat) -replace '004', '005' | Out-File 005.bat"
powershell -Command "(gc 005.bat) -replace '005', '006' | Out-File 006.bat"
and so on
```

Finally I use this:

```
call 001.bat
call 002.bat
call 003.bat
call 004.bat
call 005.bat
call 006.bat
and so on
```

But I did it all by hand, so a automated way would be amazing for all outputs of mkvtoolnix because I can use advanced renamer to change all episodes to 001, 002.. and such and filebot later to have the correct season and episode list.

Comment: Please [edit your question](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/54694837/edit) to include a [mcve] of the code you wish us to help you fix, which doesn't work as written and intended. As it stands your question is currently off-topic as it is a list of requirements, and as such effectively a free script request.

Comment: Without code your question is off topic here. In general change your batch to include a `for /l` counting loop from 1001 to 1300, and inside the loop only use the last 3 digits to overcome the problem numbers with leading zeroes being interpreted as octal.

Comment: I totally get where you guys are coming from but helping this guy took so little time.  
Without using batch functions through "call :label %var%", batch is a pain in the butt.. now he knows how it is done. 8^)

Comment: @SeñorCMasMas: I doubt answering the y-part of a [XY-Problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XY_problem) is helpful in the long run, especially when there is a short solution for the x-part.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I doubt, generating 300 nearly identical batchfiles is a good idea. Use just one and loop over your numbers:

```
@echo off
setlocal 

for /l %%i in (1,1,300) do call :processFile %%i
goto :eof

:processFile
set "number=000%1"
set "number=%number:~-3%"
echo %number%: original-%number%.mkv audio-%number%.mkv sub-%number%.mkv
REM insert your mux command here
```

Comment: I agree.. I gave him exactly what he asked for.  I probably should have mentioned that.

Comment: Stephan, I had no idea this could be done this way. I really would like to find a possible "universal" solution for this. Here's an example with your script REM 
"C:/Program Files/MKVToolNix\mkvmerge.exe" --ui-language en --output ^"F:\original\original-001 ^(1^).mkv^" --language 0:eng --default-track 0:yes --language 1:eng --default-track 1:yes ^"^(^" ^"F:\original\original-001.mkv^" ^"^)^" --no-video --language 1:por ^"^(^" ^"F:\BR001.mp4^" ^"^)^" --track-order 0:0,0:1,1:1. And for some reason it keeps looping over the same file. If it could change 001 to 002 and so on, it would be amazing.

Comment: @VitorOliveira what about replacing each `001` with the actual `%number%`, like I did in the `echo` line?

Comment: Ohhhh, I've read your message 10 times before I got it. You mean like this  "C:/Program Files/MKVToolNix\mkvmerge.exe" --ui-language en --output ^"F:\original\original-%number% ^(1^).mkv^" --language 0:eng --default-track 0:yes --language 1:eng --default-track 1:yes ^"^(^" ^"F:\original\original-%number%.mkv^" ^"^)^" --no-video --language 1:por ^"^(^" ^"F:\BR%number%.mp4^" ^"^)^" --track-order 0:0,0:1,1:1. Ohh this is going to speed up so much all the muxing!! I'm on my phone and can't test it now. Can't wait to try it out!

Comment: @VitorOliveira did you already have a chance to try? Did it work?

Comment: @Stephan, I have nothing but a big thank you to give you. I did the entire South Park tv show in a single afternoom. This was my first time trying a batch script to automate a work (better say a hobby) and it was really satisfying to see the script working with everything at once.

Answer (score 0):

Here you go.

Go down to "** and does stuff to it ** RIGHT HERE **".

This is where you will search and replace on the new file.

```
    @echo off

    :: This is the meat of the whole script..
    :: increment a number from 1 to 300
    for /L %%n in (1,1,300) do call :check_copy_file %%n
    goto :eof

    :: lines here will never execute because goto :eof is like "return" to cmd.exe

    :: ------------------------------------------------------
    :: function -- check_copy_file
    :: purpose  -- takes an input number, increments it, pads it with zeros 
    ::          -- copies original to new number name
    ::          -- ** and does stuff to it ** this is where you search and replace..
    :: ------------------------------------------------------
    :check_copy_file
    Set existing_file_num=%1
    Set /a new_file_num=%existing_file_num% +1

    call :pad_with_zeros existing_file_num %existing_file_num%
    call :pad_with_zeros new_file_num %new_file_num%

    :: ** if there isn't a batch file to copy, return
    if not exist %existing_file_num%.bat echo %existing_file_num%.bat doesn't exist!&& goto :eof

    :: copy (for instance 001.bat to 002.bat)
    copy %existing_file_num%.bat %new_file_num%.bat

    :: ** and does stuff to it ** RIGHT HERE ** 
    :: muck with the contents of %new_file_num%.bat
    echo mucky mucking with file %new_file_num%.bat

    goto :eof

    :: ---------------------------------------
    :: function -- pad_with_zeros
    :: purpose  -- adds up to two 0s as needed
    :: ---------------------------------------
    :pad_with_zeros
    Set input_var=%1
    Set input_val=%2
    if "%input_val:~2,1%"=="" Set input_val=0%input_val%
    if "%input_val:~2,1%"=="" Set input_val=0%input_val%
    Set %input_var%=%input_val%

    goto :eof
```

Comment: Oh.. one other thing.. as long as what you are editing doesn't have any of the 'special chars' in it (as in > |, etc), you can edit the file from batch also and don't need to invoke notepad++

Comment: Thank you so much for your help. For some reason, it outputs only the same from 001.bat to 002.bat. It doesn't change anything. I even tried to add :: to the first goto :eof, this should comment it, right? Is there anything else I should change on the script for it to work? I've tested here with a 001.bat file that has just something like this aaaa 001__ bbbb 001__ ccc001 and it stays the same for all the outputed files. Again thank you so much for this help.

Comment: Stephan is totally correct with his approach above.  He even did the 0 padding better than I did.